# Jacobi Elliptic function in terms of theta functions

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-functions, theta-functions

I am new to using these functions and am confused about what is a function of what.

If I want to solve $sn(x,k)$ for a given x, and use this equation:
$sn(u,k)=\frac{\theta_{2}}{\theta _{3}}\frac{\theta _{1}(u\theta _{3}^{-2})}{\theta _{4}(u\theta _{3}^{-2})}$ , would $\theta _{2}$ and $\theta _{3}$ in the equation mean $z=0$ and $q=u=x$ in the definitions of the theta functions i.e.
$\theta_{2}(z,q)\equiv \sum_{n=-\infty }^{\infty }q^{(n+1/2)^{2}}e^{(2n+1)iz}$?

And similarly, would $\theta _{1}(u\theta _{3}^{-2})$ mean that $z=0$ and $q=u\theta _{3}^{-2}$ (where $u=x$)?

Comment: use mathjax for eqns

Comment: You should construct $\theta(z,q)$ has an [infinite product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product), show that its coefficients satisfy a recursion making it $=\theta_4$, locate the periodicity, zeros $b_1,b_2$ and poles $a_1,a_2$ of $sn$ and obtain that $sn \frac{\theta(z+a_1,q)\theta(z+a_2,q)}{\theta(z+b_1,q)\theta(z+b_2,q)}$ is a bounded entire function whence constant.